# Why is my service's Dispose() method called even when I don't invoke it? (using BasicHttpBinding)

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0, dispose, idisposable

I'm taking an Intro to .NET Web Services course and one of the things we're currently learning about is the IDisposable interface. As a relatively simple example, I created a Service (Server/Client) with a `MyMethod()` operation. The method simply prints a trace statement when it's called. I also implemented IDisposable on my Server, implementing the `Dispose()` method with, again, a simple WriteLine trace in the Server implemented version.

In my client, I create two proxies with a ChannelFactory. On proxy1 I invoke the `MyMethod()` operation 3 times, then have a couple lines of code for disposing proxy1:

```
var castedProxy = (IDisposable)proxy1;
castedProxy.Dispose();
```

On proxy2, I again invoke the `MyMethod()` operation 3 times, except this time I do not cast and invoke `Dispose()`. When I run the Server/Client, I get the same traces 6 times:

> Server's Trace + CurrentThread ID
>   MyMethod()'s Trace + CurrentThread ID
>   Dispose()'s Trace + CurrentThread ID

My question is this: Why is it that the `Dispose()` portion of the trace happens every time, even though I'm only using it the first 3 traces? My guess is that it has something to do with the fact that when using BasicHttpBinding, there is no session management per se, so the old resources are still there, printing the old Dispose() calls.

Thanks in advance for any insight you are able to provide! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proxy on the client and the service on the server are two distinct objects.

For the server, the lifetime of each service object is controlled by the `InstanceContextMode` of the `ServiceBehaviour`. If this is set to `PerCall`, then a new instance of the service class will be created and destroyed for each call. WCF does this for you - you just set up the `ServiceBehaviour`.

Normally, the client and server will be in different processes. If you think of it like that, it makes sense that the lifetime of the client proxy doesn't control the lifetime of the service.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy and insightful response! Definitely answered my question 100%. :D

Answer (score 0):

You call dispose on client, not on the server. Because your WCF service is configured as per-request, then the class will be created and disposed for every call, even if client still exists.

The Dispose in service is called by default by WCF. This is normal behaviour. If service implements `IDisposable`, then `Dispose` be called when service is destroyed.